# Why it cannot get past 4096 max open files for non-root user?

Tags: 14.04, ulimit

I can't seem to increase the `nofile` limit for non-root users on Ubuntu 14.04, despite following every StackExchange answer related to this problem. So far I have:

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf
@www-data hard nofile 50000
@www-data soft nofile 50000
# even tried specifying the username directly:
myuser hard nofile 50000
myuser soft nofile 50000

$ grep 'limits' /etc/pam.d/common-session*
/etc/pam.d/common-session:session required        pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:session required        pam_limits.so

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
101232
```

Rebooted, logged in, and:

```
$ ulimit -n 4097
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

There *still* somehow seems to be a limit of 4096 max for non-root users.

Comment: I'm having the *exact same issue* on Ubuntu 16.10 desktop. No matter what I try, the limits are either 1024 or 4096.

Answer (score 13):

Using Ubuntu 14.04 I got the described hard limit:

```
user@notebook:~$ ulimit -Hn 4096
```

I could lower it using ulimit, but not increase it, just as the question describes it. As ulimit's manual describes:

> only root can increase the hard limit

So I tried to set a higher limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` like this:

```
user hard nofile 9999
```

and a fresh login like `ssh localhost -l user` gave me the new limit:

```
user@notebook:~$ ulimit -Hn 9999
```

Hope this works for you, too.

Comment: Thanks TomTomTom. I already have such a change in /etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf. I did try putting it directly into /etc/security/limits.conf as you suggested, and I still get "bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted".

Comment: I - just guess - one of two reasons, why it doesn't work for you:

Comment: Took me too long to edit the incomplete comment. Here we go:  I - just guess - one of two reasons, why this doesn't work for you:  1. `/etc/security/limits*` doesn't get read by your login mechanism - for yet unknown reason.  2. Your hard limit gets set to 4096 elsewhere, and "only root can increase ...". You might check your profiles like `.bashrc` (depending on your shell), or you might check `/etc` for other places, where limits might be set, like `find /etc | grep -e ulimit -e 4096 -e nofile`. BTW: did you try ssh? And: have you changed  `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` to avoid PAM for some reason?

Comment: Yes- all login is via ssh. I have disabled UsePAM- several guides recommend this as part of allowing only ssh-key based logins. I'll try turning it on temporarily, just to see if that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, PAM is what should read `/etc/security/limits*` - you might try to enable PAM just to check for this. I'll try disabling PAM to see, what difference it makes and will report the results.  ---  Yes! that's it! With PAM disabled my limit is 4096, too, altough set to 9999 in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: Nice sleuthing @TomTomTom. Kind of frustrating that PAM is needed to set a ulimit though.

Comment: This worked for me without messing with PAM (IDK what that is anyway). After you edit `limits.conf`, do `ulimit -n 9999` in the shell you want to increase the limit for. Check it with `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 4):

This [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/), I think addresses your issue.

Basically you should use ulimit command to increase the available resources.

For example:

Use the following command command to display maximum number of open file descriptors:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

To see the hard and soft values, issue the command as follows:

```
# ulimit -Hn
# ulimit -Sn
```

To see the hard and soft values for httpd or oracle user, issue the command as follows:

```
# su - username
```

To fix the number of maximum files, you can increase the maximum number of open files by setting a new value in kernel variable /proc/sys/fs/file-max as follows (login as the root):

```
# sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```

Above command forces the limit to 100000 files. You need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and put following line so that after reboot the setting will remain as it is. To do that, append a config directive as follows:

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

Save and close the file. Users need to log out and log back in again to changes take effect or just type the following command:

```
# sysctl -p
```

Verify your settings with command:

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

or:

```
# sysctl fs.file-max
```

The above procedure sets system-wide file descriptors (FD) limits, however you can limit `httpd` (or any other users) user to specific limits by editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` file by editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` and set the limits as follows:

```
httpd soft nofile 4096
httpd hard nofile 10240
```

Then check them by:

```
# su - httpd
$ ulimit -Hn
$ ulimit -Sn
```

If you've got the problem on other Linux distributions, check the `/etc/pam.d/login` and make sure you've got `pam_limits.so` enabled, e.g.

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Comment: Hi Brooke. Unfortunately, I have already tried the suggestions from that article. Though the 'ulimit -Hn' was new to me; it prints 4096, the limit I keep bumping into.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Service, you can try to set the limit in `/etc/systemd/system/{ServiceName}.service` add `LimitNOFILE=65536`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 not using systemd by default.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Tomcat 8 worked for me