# Will ubuntu-server have alpha/beta releases for 17.10?

Tags: server, release-management, beta

I am working on enabling Ubuntu 17.10 on a server. In order to do so I want to download ubuntu-server image for alpha2 but it is not present on
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/

I have seen beta2 ubuntu-server release on:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/

Will alpha/beta be available? If not then which image will be best to test support for 17.10 on a server?

Regards

Comment: You are not looking for the [daily builds](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/), are you?

Comment: Ubuntu server is basically a regular Ubuntu without desktop environnement. You could use any Ubuntu and use it as server, by installing the package you need (e.g. Apache).

You may want to check https://askubuntu.com/questions/31081/whats-the-difference-between-the-server-version-and-the-desktop-version

Comment: @ByteCommander:
We will not be able to integrate each daily build. I am looking for a snapshots like alpha1/2, beta1/2. Besides it does mean that daily build from target release date will be eg. beta1?

Comment: @Biggybi
I somewhat anticipate issues like different ulimits, configuration etc. from default installation. Would not that be a problem?

Comment: My knowledge reaches its limit. However, there is an [interesting thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594765/why-it-cannot-get-past-4096-max-open-files-for-non-root-user) about ulimits. Increasing ulimits seems to be quite possible.